# Redirect with React Router in onClick NavLink

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Hello I would like to be able to redirect my user to a  after the function associated with my OnClick has been performed.

This function puts a condition that the user should not be redirected every time, hence the importance of making the redirection happen after the function has been performed.

```
<BoutonSubmit  onClick={Orders}>
        Valider ma demande 
      </BoutonSubmit>

 const Orders = () => {

    if (tvideos > 0) {

=> REDIRECTION 


} else {

    openAlert();
  }
  };
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: did you try  window.location.assign or window.location.href function?

Comment: You can use `history.push("/path/to/redirect")` as you are using `react-router`.